# Disable "onclick" event in Gridview LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this template field in my gridview.

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PersonID">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="BtnPersonDashboard" Text='<%# Bind("PersonId") %>' OnClientClick='<%# "PopupPersonRecord("+ Eval("RefId") +","+Eval("MemberId")+");" %>'  />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This button is working fine, i only need to disable the button's postback. I've tried to do that in the "`RowDatabound`" event of the `Gridview` as follows:

```
  protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                // disable the Person id link button post back
                ((LinkButton)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Attributes.Add("onclick", "return false;");

            }
        }
```

However, I can't seem to get a reference to the linkbutton at all. I tried to "Watch" `e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0]` in Debug, and it's value is shown as "`Text = {1235}`" <-- my Person Id.

I'm not sure why i'm getting "`Text`" value instead of "`Linkbutton`" for that control. Any Idea what could be the problem ? Any other suggestions to a way I can disable the `onclick` event ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable postback for LinkButton, you just need to add ***return false;*** in ***OnClientClick***

```
<asp:LinkButton  
    ...
    OnClientClick='<%# "PopupPersonRecord("+ Eval("RefId") +","+Eval("MemberId")+"); return false;" %>'  />
```

***Note:*** If you do the above method, do not add `"onclick"` inside **RowDataBound event**.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    // find the control on the row on gridView
    var btnPersonDashboard = e.Row.FindControl("BtnPersonDashboard") as LinkButton;

    // check if the control was found and disable it
    if (btnPersonDashboard != null)
       btnPersonDashboard.OnClientClick = "return false";
}
```

Comment: Just change the `OnClientClick` property. I edited my post. I'm glad to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Just disable it in code behind.

```
BtnPersonDashboard.Enabled = false;
```